# AWS Document DB - Spring Boot Integration - Commit behavior for WRITE Ops

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a Spring Boot application (`2.2.5 RELEASE`) that **sync** (not reactive) writes to AWS DocumentDB wo declaring any explicit transaction semantics from application. We are using `MongoOperations` without declaring an explicit `MongoTransactionManager`

In this setup, for MongoDB 4.X Replica-Set, we get "auto-committed" writes if an explicit transaction is not initiated by client. see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/default-commit-behavior-mongo-4-x/125859)

However, we would like to understand, using the same Mongo Java driver version `3.11.2` , [compatible](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/) with MongoDB Server version `4.2.X`, when we execute a WRITE operation on a DocumentDB Cluster (having a replica Set), without initiating explicit Transaction from Client (i.e. spring boot app), when or how exactly the database commit takes place? We have seen closely spaced updates-after-insert (within <50 ms) to fail stating update wasn't able to find the inserted record.

It appears that the same behavior as MongoDB, i.e. "auto-committed" is probably not applicable with "DocumentDB". In that case how WRITEs are committed?

Can someone help us understand the underlying behavior? We couldn't find any relevant section in the [AWS DocumentDB Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html) that elaborates on the WRITE Ops wo Transactions.

Also, does DocumentDB use a Single Threaded WRITE approach on a collection or how is it?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DocumentDB uses a distributed storage volume and data is replicated 6 times across three availability zones. The distributed storage uses 10GB chunks as logical unit. When writing data, Amazon DocumentDB ensures that all writes are durably recorded, using a write quorum of 4.
After 4 copies of data are written to storage, data can be considered committed and the Primary instance will send an acknowledgment to the client.
Data is further copied to other 2 chunks to a total of 6, as mentioned before.

There is good information in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html) about read and write consistency, but let me know if you require further clarification.